# Add a key from downloaded file

Tags: command-line, apt

```
curl -s http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/ubuntu/precise/amd64/cdh/archive.key | apt-key add -
```

This is the statement I am using to download a key and add to it. It works fine. But I want to do it in the following way

> Download the key from URL and add it

I have downloaded it into `/usr/local`.

```
/usr/local/archive.key | apt-key add -
```

I tried this. But I am getting the following error

```
usr/local/archive.key: 1: usr/local/archive.key: -----BEGIN: not found
usr/local/archive.key: 2: usr/local/archive.key: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Any ideas to achieve it from the downloaded file?

What's the wrong in my `file | apt-key add -` syntax? Will it consider the thing before to pipe as URL?

Comment: Use your home folder (`/home/<username>`, abbreviation `~`) to download things to, not `/usr`, so you don’t need root access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type in `file | apt-key add -` you tell the system to execute the file and feed the output to `apt-key`.

If you want to feed the content of file to `apt-key` you should use:

`cat file  | apt-key add -`

**edit**

As long as you have execute permissions for that file the system will try to execute it. The system reads the few bytes at the beginning of the file (i.e. `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/usr/bin/python` or the binary executable header) and tries to figure out how exactly should it execute it. In your case it finds the beginning of the key: **-----BEGIN**, has no idea how to execute it and gives you somewhat cryptic error message.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation man +one. execute the file in the sense? Can it be any type of file?

Answer (score 1):

It's a syntax error. From [Man page](http://man.he.net/man8/apt-key)

```
apt-key [--keyring filename] [command] [arguments...]
```

So, it should be

```
apt-key add /usr/local/archive.key
```